# Need to save multiple Correlated value to CSV or Txt file using JMeter plugin HTTP Simple Table Server

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Txt file is showing empty when i am trying to save Correlated value to CSV or Txt file using JMeter plugin HTTP Simple Table Server?

please find the steps i did
Step 1: File initialization kept in setUp Thread Group
[Initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E6bJ.png)

Step 2: correlated value is in Ultimate thread group, so i have placed adding in thread group end
using below help
POST : http://hostname:port/sts/ADD
POST Parameters : FILENAME=file.txt,LINE=D0001123,ADD_MODE=[FIRST,LAST],UNIQUE=[FALSE,TRUE]
[For Adding using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pBfY.png)

not throwing any errors but file is showing empty

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call [SAVE](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#SAVE) endpoint in order to flush the dataset to the file

[image]

You may find approach with [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) and [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) easier to use

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your continuous support towards our JMeter community. My manager suggest to use simple table server as we are using master slave for load test.